# How to Find All Possible String Combinations Within 2 Different Size String Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string, combinations, permutation

I am running into a peculiar problem of which i couldn't find any solution after long search.
Here is my question:

I have two String Arrays:

```
   var arr1 = new[] { "UserId", "BookId", "BookStoreId", "Appid" };
   var arr2 = new[] {"Same", "Unique", "Repetitive"};
```

I want Result with all possible combinations like:

Result (Should be in tabular format):

Columns-     UserId  BookId  BookStoreId Appid

- Row1       Same   Same    Same    Same
- Row2       Same   Same    Same    Unique
- Row3       Same   Same    Same    Repetitive
- Row4       Same   Same    Unique  Same
- Row5           Same   Same    Repetitive  Same
- Row6           Same   Same    Unique  Unique
- Row6           Same   Same    Unique  Repetitive
- Row7         Same Same    Repetitive  Unique
- Row8         Same Same    Repetitive  Repetitive
- Row9         Same Unique  Same    Same
- Row10        Same Unique  Unique  Same
- Row11        Same Repetitive  Same    Same
  and so on...

Rows and Columns are only for notation purpose.

I hope my question is clear now.

I Should create 64 Unique Combinations.

I have tried lots of ways including Cartesian products but that didnt solved my problem.

Comment: how about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328079/calculate-all-possible-pairs-of-items-from-two-lists) ?

Comment: So you want all possible combinations with length 4 of items in `arr2`? See [permutation with repetions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629938/1997232).

Comment: @MongZhu This doesn't give expected output, I want result in table format  with ColumnNames as arr1 values and Rows as Arr2 Values.

Comment: You are counting : 0000,0001,0002,0003, 0010, 0011, 0012,0013,0020,0021,0022,0023,0030,0031,0032,0033,0100,0101,0102,0103,...

Comment: @Sinatr That solution doesnt fit my question,That solution is about permutations of single array elements within them, not what i am looking for.

Comment: "I Should create 64 Unique Combinations." I don't see why it would only be 64. Each of the elements can be any of the 7 strings, right? So there should be 7^4=2401 combinations. Your question isn't very clear at the moment... (It's also not really obvious why your first example uses everything from `arr1`, but all your others only use items from `arr2`. What's the relevance of that?)

Comment: @JonSkeet , Consider arr1 elements as column names and arr2 elements as their values,keeping the column names static we need to swap values dynamically for all possible unique combinations with repetitions. Consider the resultset as a table(it might not be visible like that), see my edited question.

Comment: So actually the first array is irrelevant in terms of coming up with combinations? Or is it just that that provides the *length* of the combinations you need? (If so, it would be helpful not to bother even showing the string array - you basically want a method accepting a string array of options, and the number of items per row.)

Answer (score 3):

Seems to you need a Combinations With Repetitions. 
Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25824818/1007620

Summary:

```
static IEnumerable<String> CombinationsWithRepition(IEnumerable<string> input, int length)
{
    if (length <= 0)
        yield return "";
    else
    {
        foreach(var i in input)
            foreach(var c in CombinationsWithRepition(input, length-1))
                yield return i + ',' + c;
    }
}
```

Then

```
string[] items = {"UserId", "BookId", "BookStoreId", "Appid", "Same", "Unique", "Repetitive"};
foreach (var c in CombinationsWithRepition(items, 4))
    Console.WriteLine (c);
```

Result https://pastebin.com/2hCbA1XJ

Comment: Not what i expect, Consider arr1 elements as column names and arr2 elements as their values,keeping the column names static we need to swap values dynamically for all possible unique combinations with repetitions. Consider the resultset as a table(it might not be visible like that), see my edited question

Comment: then use the same code and remove `arr1` elements out of the items, you'll get 3^4 = 81 combinations

Comment: @KienChu  Thanks, It worked well, i was overthinking of arr1 it seems...